# apache mod_rewrite rule matches but returns a 404 error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I'm on a shared linux hosting plan from godaddy, trying to get mod_rewrite to work.  The url `/products/4` should show the page at `/products/?id=4` but instead it returns a 404 file not found error.

Here's the .htaccess file in the products folder:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "products/([0-9]+)/" "products/index.php?id=$1" [L]
```

There are no errors in any logs.  Why is this not working, is it something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define start and end of pattern for example :

```
RewriteRule "^search/(.*)$" "/search.php?term=$1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I added the caret and dollar signs but no change.  I also tried with and without forward slashes at the start and end but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after some sleep (turns out, that's necessary).  Moved the script at `/products/index.php` to `/products.php` and put the following in `/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^products/([0-9]+)/?$" "products.php?id=$1" [L]
```

Now `/products/{id}` is correctly rewritten to `/products.php?id={id}`.